# Returning an Image from Byte Array in Java AWS lambda API Response

Tags: java, arrays, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Image file 001.jpg in my Aws S3 bukcet.
I am trying to download that file using Java.Below is a piece of code which is for downloading image file from s3 bucket.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s3Key)) {
        AmazonS3Connector s3 = AmazonS3Connector.getInstance();
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            final S3Object s3Object = s3.getClient().getObject(S3_BUCKET_NAME, s3Key);
            final S3ObjectInputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
            data = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            s3Object.close();
            String fileName = s3Key.split("/")[1];
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();
            MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
            responseHeaders.put("Content-type", mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(s3Key));
            responseHeaders.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
            responseHeaders.put("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

            return APIResponse.builder()
                    .setStatusCode(200)
                    .setObjectBody(data)
                    .setHeaders(responseHeaders)
                    .build();
        } catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File does not exists");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            new OutwinErrorQueue().exception(e).log();
        }
    }
```

After running this, Image file is getting downloaded but while opening below error is coming.

[image]

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
    public void downloadFile(String fileName) {
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, fileName);
        S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        try {
            byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
            ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", new File("path/to/output.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The AWSconfig is like this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class AmazonConfig {

        private final String ACCESS_KEY = "*****KEY*****";
        private final String SECRET_KEY = "*****KEY*****";

        @Bean
        public AmazonS3 s3() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withRegion("ap-south-1")
                .build();

        }
    }
```

you can also get URL of that file using `s3Client.getUrl(bucketName, fileName).toString();` when you are saving the image file.

dependency I used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.931</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I have edited question. Still it is not working.

Comment: I have the URL of my image like this https://reddit-clone-spring-boot.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1634299258114_big-sur-mountains-night-dark-macos-big-sur-stock-california-1366x768-1493.jpg and the name of the file is `1634299258114_big-sur-mountains-night-dark-macos-big-sur-stock-california-1366x768-1493.jpg`. I just modify the `public void downloadFile(String fileName)` method. Try with that.

Comment: It will store Image file to the path of the location, What I need is I want to return this image in api response. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: You can return this in the form of a URL in the response.